# paste 3 duplicate dates in 3 cells with each paste incrementing date up by 1 day

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to paste 3 duplicate dates in 3 cells with each paste incrementing the date forward by 1 day.

This would be all done in row a, i.e. 11/24/17 11/24/17 11/24/17 11/25/17 11/25/17 11/25/17 11/26/17 11/26/17 11/26/17..... Is there a function in excel which would handle this or is there a formula that I can use?  I'm running Excel, Version 15.4 on a Mac - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fill A1, B1, C1 with starting value. D1=A1+1, then prolong the formula to the right as far as you need (and let cells stretch to content or you can see ###### instead of values).